# Is mod_ssl is available for apache2.2.15?

Tags: apache-2.2

Even after lots of googleing I could not found mod_ssl which support apache2.2.15.

available packages are for apache1.3.

Can anybody help?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

mod_ssl is included in the httpd source distribution. Your distro probably has it in a separate package.

Comment: How can i find that mod_ssl is included.

Comment: In the source distribution? You look in the source distribution and there it is.

Comment: yes mod_ssl.c is available there.Now how can I use that when i have already installed apache. or If i install apache again then how can i enable mod_ssl.

Comment: Install the package provided with your distro that contains it.